# brighter PDF output for printing purpose

Tags: printing

To print a long PDF and save the toner, the basic solution is to have brighter text like the 50 percent gray color (RGB(128,128,128)). It is easy to set up the document to have all the text in the gray, however, I also want to apply the same idea to all the figures and every component of the PDF. The question is:

**Is there any method that applies a filter to every component of PDF to make it brighter and more convenient for printing?**

I know there are softwares that do this operation, however latex is an amazing world that I expect it to have a nice solution!

Comment: Can someone please improve the tags?

Answer (score 3):

Look into the properties of your printer, many have options which do exactly this. For example for my printer, it's the `fast` printing quality.

[image]